# UIAlertView makes the program crash

Tags: ios7, uialertview

I've got a crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue performTask:] may only be called from the main thread.'
```

And I could not find a solution for 2 days.
And here is the code:

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
UIAlertView *noTicketAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Aradığınız kriterlere uygun bilet bulunamadı!" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Tamam" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[noTicketAlert show];
```

Comment: Care to show us your code for the alert view?

Comment: This should have crashed in Xcode 4 and Xcode 3.

Comment: I don't think the error message could be much more explicit.

Comment: it is xcode 5, the program is working xcode 3 and 4. I tried to upgrade my application for ios7, but uialertview makes my application crash

Comment: It seems you are using two alert instances. Can you give full code ?

Comment: yeah i realized it, I'm trying to fix it. Thank you :)

Comment: I am using two alert, one starts first, if an error occurs, I dismiss first one and show second one to user, that's where my code is crashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I've found the solution and I share that with you guys. 
I tried to override the `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex` function, and sent unique buttonIndexes 
like `9999` for each of my alerts.
That is,

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    [self viewWillDisappear:YES];
    if(buttonIndex == 9999) {
        noTicketAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Aradığınız kriterlere uygun bilet bulunamadı!" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Tamam" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [noTicketAlert show];
    }
}
```

and if I want to display the noticketAlert, I call this method like :

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:9999 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 10):

I triggered this error by attempting to display an alert from a background thread. Fixed like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:...
    [alertView show];
});
```

Answer (score 8):

I got this error when presenting a UIAlertView normally (no funny button override stuff).  It turned out that I was presenting it twice in quick succession.  The fix in my case was to remove the erroneous duplicate call.

If you do need to present two alert views at close to the same time, and you get this error, then a fix that works (and addresses the error message itself) is to run the code on the main thread:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^
    {
    // Your code that presents the alert view(s)
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom button make sure you implement the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    return YES;
}
```

if this selector is not found then the program with crash..

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for the Swift 2 answer to this issue, I ran into a similar problem and solved it with @Dave Batton's solution

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: self)
})
```