# Creating UIAlertView multiple times in a quick succession

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

In my app, I intend have two (or more) devices sharing and merging NSDictionaries. I have Multipeer Connectivity working flawlessly, I'm just running into an issue when it comes down to merging the two dictionaries on each transfer. I have two "for" loops right now that iterate through both dictionaries. If there is a key/value pair that already exists, the user is prompted if they would like to overwrite the object that already exists or keep it. They have the options of keeping the current object in question, overwriting the current object, keeping all conflicting objects, or overwriting all conflicting objects. The code I have so far:

```
-(void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID{

pathChooser = 1;

NSLog(@"DATA RECEIVED: %d bytes!", data.length);

dataReceived = data;

receivedDataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

receivedDataDict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataReceived];

for (key1 in receivedDataDict) {

    NSLog(@"%@", key1);

    if ([dataDict objectForKey:key1] == nil) {

        NSLog(@"Writing new folder");

        [dataDict setObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] forKey:key1];

    }

    for (key2 in [receivedDataDict objectForKey:key1]) {

        if ([[dataDict objectForKey:key1] objectForKey:key2] == nil) {

            NSLog(@"Writing a new file");

            [[dataDict objectForKey:key1] setObject:[[receivedDataDict objectForKey:key1] objectForKey:key2] forKey:key2];

        }

        else{

            if (pathChooser == 1) {

                NSLog(@"MADE IT TO -ALREADY EXISTS-");

                UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Match %@ already exists in %@!", key2, key1]

                                                           message: @"Overwrite?"

                                                          delegate: self

                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Keep"

                                                 otherButtonTitles:@"Overwrite", @"Keep All", @"Overwrite All",nil];

                [alert1 show];

            }

            else if (pathChooser == 3){

                NSLog(@"Path 3");

                [[dataDict objectForKey:key1] setObject:[[receivedDataDict objectForKey:key1] objectForKey:key2] forKey:key2];

            }

        }

    }

}

[dataDict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

NSLog(@"%@", dataDict);

receivedDataDict = nil;

}



// Buttons for UIAlertView...

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert1 clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

//Keep Current

if (buttonIndex == 0) {

    pathChooser = 1;

}



//Overwrite Current

else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

    [[dataDict objectForKey:key1] setObject:[[receivedDataDict objectForKey:key1] objectForKey:key2] forKey:key2];

}



//Keep All

else if (buttonIndex == 2) {

    pathChooser = 2;

}



//Overwrite All

else if (buttonIndex == 3) {

    pathChooser = 3;

}



}
```

The problem I have occurs when there are multiple similar key/value pairs between the two NSDictionaries, which creates the UIAlertView several times in rapid succession, which is apparently not a good thing. Is there a way I can delay each creation of UIAlertView? Is there a more obvious solution than that? I've tried using a code block and the code block doesn't appear to read the "key1" and "key2" values because they appear as "(null)" in the UIAlertView. I have also tried this approach in the line after [alert1 show]:

```
 while ((!alert1.hidden) && (alert1.superview != nil))

                    {

                        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] limitDateForMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

                    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work until after the second time the UIAlertView is created. The error I'm getting is:

**Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue performTask:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:388**

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue performTask:] may only be called from the main thread.'**

Any suggestions are welcome and I will try all. I couldn't find many other people with the same problem as I was having.

Comment: I found this when searching for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005463/uialertview-makes-the-program-crash

Answer (score 5):

You could always do a 'dispatch_async' on creating the UIAlertView's.

So, it would end up looking like:

```
__block UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Match %@ already exists in %@!", key2, key1]
                                                        message:@"Overwrite?"
                                                       delegate:weakSelf
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Keep"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Overwrite", @"Keep All", @"Overwrite All",nil];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

    [alert1 show];
});
```

Comment: Ok, that worked so far. There is no error any more, so thanks a ton! However, how would I go about making sure that the code doesn't advance past the UIAlertView block until the user has responded to it? (so that the "overwrite all" and "keep all" options would take effect and stop the next alert views)